# Get Bool from C# Class, Send to form

Tags: c#, winforms, class

So i have this class called

> **BinaryKeyInterchanger.cs**

in that class i have the following code.

> ```
> public class BinaryKeyInterchanger
> {
>     internal void MapEscape(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         bool Esc = e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape;
>     }
> }
> ```

From that i want to send it to this section of code in form1.

> ```
>        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(StoredKeys, true))
>         {
>             if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) ///--- < and use it like this.
>             {
>                 // write the key with a space
>                 string Esc = "{ESC}";
>                 sw.Write(Esc);
>             }
>         }
> ```

Is this possible and how would i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to open your stream in your class constructor, then just write to it in your MapEscape function?  If you do this you may want to implement IDisposable to close the stream.

Comment: to be frank, i've never really used classes before, just used to doing everything in the forms code. just trying to get a better grasp of it. thats all. :)

Comment: In what portion of the code is the second snippet is? That is, what does trigger the writting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TONS of different ways you could do this. Here is one of them.

```
public static class BinaryKeyInterchanger
{
    internal static bool MapEscape(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        return e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape;
    }
}
```

Made it a static "helper" function.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(StoredKeys, true))
{
    if (BinaryKeyInterchanger.MapEscape(e))
    {
        sw.Write("{ESC}");
    }
}
```

For this example, I made the assumption that the form code is happening inside of an event that has KeyEventArgs e in the signature. Like I said, there are plenty of other ways to do this as well but this should work.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what i was thinking. just couldn't work out the code.